# Quadratic Equation in C

Tags: c

Here is a program that I'm trying to fix. I entered 1,5,6 and there should be 2 solutions and it said only 1 solution exists. I'm also trying to make it display decimal values(should I use double?). Below is my code, What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int inputs[3], a, b, c, d, x, x1, x2, i, lastDigit;
    char *os, *noSol = "No solution\n", *cont = 'y';

    while (cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y')
    {
        printf("This program solves a quadratic equation\n");
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {

            lastDigit = i % 10;
            if (i >= 4 && i <= 20)
                os = "th";
            if (i == 1 || lastDigit == 1)
                os = "st";
            else if (i == 2 || lastDigit == 2)
                os = "nd";
            else if (i == 3 || lastDigit == 3)
                os = "rd";
            else
                os = "th";


            printf("Enter your %d%s number: ", i, os);
            scanf("%d", &inputs[i - 1]);
        }

        a = inputs[0];
        b = inputs[1];
        c = inputs[2];

        while (1)
        {
            if (a == 0)
            {
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    printf(noSol);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    x = -c / b;
                    printf("The equation is not quadratic and the solution is %d\n", x);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                d = pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
                if (d < 0)
                {
                    printf(noSol);
                    break;
                }
                else if (d == 0)
                {
                    x1 = -b / 2 * a;
                    printf("One solution: %d\n", x1);
                    break;
                }
                else  if (d > 0)
                {
                    x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
                    x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
                    printf("Two solutions: %d and %d\n", x1, x2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("Run program second time? ( Y / N )\n");
        scanf("%s", &cont);
    }
    getch();
  }
```

Comment: Works for me:

This program solves a quadratic equation
Enter your 1st number: 1
Enter your 2nd number: 5
Enter your 3rd number: 6
Two solutions: -2 and -3

Comment: You don't want to use `int` when solving quadratic equations, otherwise you are up to VERY confusing rounding artefacts.

Comment: Also, more comments on your code: all the `2 * a` factors should be in parens, since `x / 2 * a` is interpreted as `(x / 2) * a`

Comment: @thesamet I get only one result with those same numbers. It prints "One solution: -2"

Comment: You're not handling "cont" correctly, which will result in a runtime error, but otherwise it's able to calculate the factors correctly (for the 1, 5, 6 input): http://ideone.com/vgBfs6  How about setting a break point (or adding debug output) to try to find out how d ends up equaling 0 for you?

Comment: I'm using Dev C++, Interesting that ideone gives a different result.

Comment: What is the point of the while (1) loop?  As far as I can tell, this loop will *always* be broken out of in the first iteration, regardless of the `if` branch taken.

Comment: You can find the imaginary roots too. Here is the code for that: http://cstartercodes.blogspot.in/2015/02/solution-of-quadratic-equation.html

Answer (score 3):

Many issues

1. The math part should use `double` (or `float`) instead of `int`.

   `double inputs[3], a, b, c, d, x, x1, x2;`
2. `printf()` & `scanf()` for double, format specifier needs to change from `%d` to `%le` (or the like) to match `double`.
3. Math error: in 3 places, `/ 2 * a;` should be `/ (2 * a);`
4. `char *cont = 'y'` should be `char cont[2] = "y"`
5. `scanf("%s", &cont);` should be `scanf("%1s", cont);`.
6. Error handling: the return value of `scanf()` should be checked as in

   `if (1 != scanf("%lf", &inputs[i - 1])) { ; /* Handle error */ }`
7. Minor math: `if (d == 0)` case results in a "double root", not a single solution.  Practically speaking, given floating point math rounding, one does not always know `d` should have been mathematically *exactly* zero and thus the "single" root is really 2 very close roots.  Further, with select values, the "Two solutions" will have the same value should `sqrt(d)` be much much smaller than `b`.